# Upload failure: Quota exceeded: Your table exceeded quota for imports or query appends per table. For more information

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to upload old backup data in to bigquery table. It fails at times with the error below. It's not clear which quota is exceeded, how do we find it or workaround this error?

```
{
  "errorResult" : {
  "message" : "Quota exceeded: Your table exceeded quota for imports or query appends per table. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors",
  "location" : "load_job_per_table.long",
  "reason" : "quotaExceeded"
  },
  "state" : "DONE",
  "errors" : [
    {
      "reason" : "quotaExceeded",
      "location" : "load_job_per_table.long",
      "message" : "Quota exceeded: Your table exceeded quota for imports or query appends per table. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is most likely [Load Jobs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#import) Limits:

Like **Daily limit** : 1,000 load jobs per table per day (including failures), 10,000 load jobs per project per day (including failures)

Comment: I looked that up, I am pretty sure the daily upload limit was not hit and the error message doesn't say what quota is exceeded causing to this confusion.

Comment: The error message includes "imports or query appends per table", which is the 1000 append-per-table limit Mikhail referenced. These apply to both load jobs and query jobs that specify a destination table.

Answer (score 0):

Your project can make up to 1,500 table modifications per table per day, whether the modification appends data, updates data, or truncates the table. This limit cannot be changed and includes the combined total of all load jobs, copy jobs, and query jobs that append to or overwrite a destination table.

see: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#standard_tables