# Big Query API - Quota exceeded: Your table exceeded quota for UPDATE or DELETE queries per table

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

As described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37126385/upload-failure-quota-exceeded-your-table-exceeded-quota-for-imports-or-query-a) question there's a quota limit for how many updates you might do per day.

I've looked up the docs and this part caught my attention:

```
Daily update limit: 1,000 updates per table per day; applies only to the destination table in a query.
```

The problem is that I didn't ran 1000 updates on my table (maybe 80.. 150 max)

So I'd like to know either if there's a solution for this or the docs are out of date.

Thanks.

**EDIT**
This only happens if I use the Big Query API, I'm able to update tables through the console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are using DML

Per documentation:

> DML statements are significantly more expensive to process than SELECT
>   statements.
>
> ```
> Maximum UPDATE/DELETE statements per day per table: 48 
> Maximum UPDATE/DELETE statements per day per project: 500 
> Maximum INSERT statements per day per table: 1,000 
> Maximum INSERT statements per day per project: 10,000
> ```

You can see more details in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language)

The quota you referenced in your question related to Query - see more [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#queries)